# Submit form using <a> tag after confirm

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to submit a form through a tag. I have tried triggering document.myform.submit(), this.form.submit(), parentNode.submit() etc. but none of this is working! Using a submit button or remove confirm() the code works fine. But I want to use both of them. Need some help.

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return confirmm('Delete this record?');">
    <a href="" class="deleteThisRecord" type="submit" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit();" name="delete">
        Delete This Record
    </a>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<{$listData[I]['id']}>">
</form>


function confirmm($confirmText = 'Delete?') {
    var dicision = confirm($confirmText);
    if (dicision) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The [*type*](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html-markup-20110525/a.html#a.attrs.type) attribute for A elements is a MIME type, "submit" is not a valid value. Perhaps you're thinking of button and input type submit elements? Also, as an in-line listener, you can simply do `this.form.submit()`. The simplest solution is to use a span element instead and style it to look like a button (or just use a button).

Answer (score -1):

Give an id attribute to a form, and call submite to this id reference document, getById('yourIdName').submit();

Comment: How is that different to what the OP is already doing?